# Laravel Replicate from ID

Tags: laravel

I am trying to duplicate a record and edit the new record but I'm struggling to understand how i'll look up the new record inside my method.

My route is

```
Route::get('courses/duplicate/{id}', ['as' => 'courses.duplicate', 'uses' => 'backend\CoursesController@duplicate']);
```

which when i DD inside my controller is giving me the ID of 6675.

Here's my method:

```
public function duplicate(Request $request, $id)
{
    //dd($id);
    $course = Course::findOrFail($id)->replicate()->save();
    return 'Course duplicated';
}
```

All I would like to do is add '- copy' to the new records title. How do get the ID of the new record so I can do a findOrFail within that method?

Comment: Have you tried `$course->id`?

Comment: I since changed a line to 

return 'Course duplicated with course id' . ' ' . $course->id ;

and got Trying to get property of non-object for that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function duplicate(Request $request, $id){
//dd($id);
    $course = Course::findOrFail($id)->replicate();
    $course->save();
    $newid = $course->id;
    return 'Course duplicated';
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: It was. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $course = Course::findOrFail($id)->replicate();
    $course->save();
    dd( $course->id );//TODO;
```